# How to use a single-header library C file in Rust?

Tags: c, rust, header, shared-libraries

I have been researching this topic about 2 days. I found bindgen, cc, windows-dll, libc, dlopen or other rust crates. But I couldn't able to use a single-header library. I made the c library so I checked my library if my library has the problem but in python I can able to use. I saw this [FFI RUST](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#foreign-function-interface) resource and I reviewed.

**My OS:** Windows 11

**Rust/Cargo Version:** 1.64

**Visual Studio:** 2022 Community

**Single-Header C lib:** [Github](https://github.com/hanilr/variation-ui)

**Main File:** *main.rs*

```rust
#[link(name = "lib-name")] // This link name want '.a' or '.dll' extension I think
extern { fn vn_clear; } // Extern c function

fn main()
{
   unsafe { vn_clear(); } // 'unsafe' for FFI
   println!("Is this worked?");
}
```

I know this code would work every FFI library but I couldn't figured it out.

```ini
[package]
name = "rust-test"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
libc = "0.2.133"
```

Do you know a way to use a single-header C library in Rust?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Comment: Yes, if you follow the https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/ you can able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most certainly want to use [`bindgen`](https://crates.io/crates/bindgen) to generate the function definitions in Rust from the C header file.

There is an [excellent step-by-step tutorial](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-bindgen/) that creates such a binding for the `bzip2` library. It should give you an idea of the steps required to achieve what you need.